# Pouchdb Combining Data from Multiple Databases in map function

Tags: pouchdb

I have an Database with docs and another with categories now I want to combine booth in an map reduce view like:

```
var categoryMapper = [...]
var viewName = 'byMonthAndCat10';
var index = {
    _id: '_design/'+viewName,
    views: {
        byMonthAndCat10: {
            map: function (doc) {
                if (doc.bookingDate) {
                    var date = moment(doc.bookingDate, moment.ISO8601_FORMAT);
                    categoryMappers.forEach(function(mapper) {
                        if(doc[mapper.field].indexOf(mapper.value)) {
                            emit([date.year(), date.month(), date.day()], [mapper.category, doc.debit+doc.credit]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.toString()
        }
    }
};
```

But the map function is stringified and so doesn't know about categorymapper anymore. How do I handle this? I could prepend the categorymapper array as string but that's not very nice, or?

Comment: Also you should really consider just using bookingDate as the _id. If it's in ISO format, then you can do any fancy date range operation you want on it, just using allDocs.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to solve this is to include the categoryId as a field in your document, and then join them together using [linked documents](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database). (Search "linked documents" on that page.)

If your data is very relational, though, you might also want to look into the [relational pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/relational-pouch) plugin, which can do a lot of this boilerplate for you, so you can write less code.

Comment: The Problem is that I have to go trough all categoryMappers in order to find out the categoryId. I thought I could use the map/reduce approach to speed up procedure. But therefore I would need to supply all map function calls with the categoryMappers

Comment: I understand; I'm just suggesting an alternate way of doing what you're trying to do. If you want to continue down the same path, though, you would need to use [a closure](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database) (search the word "closures"). However this is really bad for performance, and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it know like this (so basically without map functionality of pouch):

```
Transactions.allDocs({include_docs: true, endkey: '_'}).then(function (response) {
    var result = [];
    response.rows.forEach(function (row) {
        var doc = row.doc;
        var date = moment(doc.bookingDate, moment.ISO8601_FORMAT);
        var yearMonth = date.year()*100+date.month();
        categoryMappers.forEach(function(mapper) {
            switch(mapper.type) {
                case "contains":
                    if(doc[mapper.field].indexOf(mapper.value)) {
                        if(result.hasOwnProperty(yearMonth)) {
                            if(result[yearMonth].hasOwnProperty(mapper.category)) {
                                result[yearMonth][mapper.category] += doc.debit + doc.credit;
                            }
                            else {
                                result[yearMonth][mapper.category] = doc.debit + doc.credit;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            result[yearMonth] = {month: date.year()+'-'+date.month()};
                            result[yearMonth][mapper.category] = doc.debit + doc.credit;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default: throw new Error("CategoryMapper type not implemented yet!");
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
}).catch(function(err){ console.error(err); Transactions.info(console.debug); });
```